# Is there any alternative to using eval in a shell script to achieve variable expansion

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have the following case where exec and eval will handle variables passed as arguments differently.
Here, eval seems to output something which is intended.

But is there any alternative to using that?

```
$ cat arg.sh 
#!/bin/bash

eval ./argtest $*

$ ./arg.sh "arg1 'subarg1 subarg2'"
Args: 2
Arg1: arg1
Arg2: subarg1 subarg2
```

But at the same time if I use exec instead of eval call, the single quotes are not getting honored.

```
$ ./arg.sh "arg1 'subarg1 subarg2'"
Args: 3
Arg1: arg1
Arg2: 'subarg1
Arg3: subarg2'
```

Comment: Why not just `./argtest "$@"` and `./arg.sh arg1 'subarg1 subarg2'`?

Comment: `achieve variable expansion` Are you _sure_ you want variable expansion? Your example shows quotes parsing or interpretation, there is no variable expansion...

Answer (score 0):

You *should* do:

```
#!/bin/bash    
./argtest "$@"
```

To properly pass unchanged arguments.

Then do:

```
$ ./arg.sh arg1 'subarg1 subarg2'
```

As you would do with any other command.

Research when to use quoting in shell, how is `$@` positional arguments expansions handled specially in quotes, research how does `$*` and `$@` differ and research word splitting. Also research what is variable expansion and in which contexts it happens and how does single quotes differ from double quotes. And because exec is mentioned see [bashfaq Eval command and security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Remember to check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net .

> Is there any alternative to using eval in a shell script to achieve variable expansion

Yes - use `envsubst` for variable expansion, it's a tool just for that.

```
#!/bin/bash
arg=$(VARIABLE=something envsubst '$VARIABLE' <<<"$1")
./argtest "$arg"

$ bash -x ./arg.sh 'string with **not-expanded** $VARIABLE'
+ ./argtest 'string with **not-expanded** something'
```

> Is there any alternative to using eval in a shell script to achieve *single quotes parsing

Yes - you would potentially write your own parser, probably in `awk`, that would split the string and then reload. A very very crude example:

```
#!/bin/bash
readfile -t args < <(sed "s/ *'\([^']*\)' */\n\1\n/; s/\n$//" <<<"$*")
./argtest "${args[@]}"

$ bash -x ./arg.sh  "arg1 'subarg1 subarg2'"
+ ./argtest 'arg1' 'subarg1 subarg2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using $*, the shell applies word splitting to the parameters and passes the effect after word splitting  to `eval`, repsepcitvely `exec`. What happens after, differs between them:

`exec` simply **replaces** the current process by a new one, based on the first parameter it gets. Than in passes the remaining parameters **unmodified** to this process.

`eval` on the other hand **catenates** the parameters together to a single string (using one space as a separator between those strings), then treats this resulting string as a **new command** where the usual expansion and word splitting mechanism of bash are applied, and finally runs this command.

The mechanism is completely different, which is not surprising, since these commands serve a different purpose.